# What is the difference between deleting a job vs pod scale down to zero

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I wanted to stop my job for sometime. What would be the recommended approach for it?

1. If  I delete job then it will delete all pods associated to the job.yaml file .
2. Scalling down pods to zero using deployment.

Please let me know is there any way to get adverse results if choose option1 over option2.

Comment: Thanks Lei for quick reply . The above link is not fit for my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

If the `job` is spawned by a `cronjob`, then you can just delete the `job` resource and `suspend` the `cronjob` (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#suspend). Also see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#cron-job-limitations) regarding "missed jobs" which will happen while the `cronjob` is suspended).

Then when you are ready to resume, just `unsuspend` the `cronjob`, and the next triggered cycle will re-create the `job` resource

If the job is created outright (i.e. not from a `cronjob`), then you can [suspend the job itself](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/12/introducing-suspended-jobs/) if you are on Kubernetes 1.21 or later. If you aren't, then the easiest way (I think), is to dump the job yaml to disk, delete the job itself from the cluster, then recreate it when you're ready to resume.

If you are running the job as a `deployment` (your point #2), and not as a `job` resource then, yes, simply scaling down to zero then scaling back up would work.

Comment: What is the CLI command to suspend the job ?

Comment: You would edit the job in-cluster to add the `suspend: true` directive as shown in the example on the linked documentation.